# Oracle Developer to work in PHPmyAdmin, syntax error

Tags: mysql, oracle

I need to work into php, so I want to move my database (inside oracle sql developer) to my phpmyadmin, I'm working locally.

Here is the code anyway...

I think varchar2 it's not recognized by mysql syntax.
The same happend with numeric.
But when it create a key with auto_increment or something like this, It appears an error, at least this happend to me.

```
-- Generado por Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 18.2.0.179.0756
--   en        2018-07-29 004217 CLT
--   sitio      Oracle Database 11g
--   tipo      Oracle Database 11g

CREATE TABLE alumno (
    id_alumno            varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre               varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    apellido             varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    ciudad               varchar(25),
    region               varchar(25),
    carrera_id_carrera   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE alumno ADD CONSTRAINT alumno_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_alumno );

CREATE TABLE asignatura (
    id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre          varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    horario         varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE asignatura ADD CONSTRAINT asignatura_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_asignatura );

CREATE TABLE carrera (
    id_carrera           varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre               varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    escuela_id_escuela   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE carrera ADD CONSTRAINT carrera_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_carrera );

CREATE TABLE contrato (
    id_contrato            VARCHAR2(25 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    cargo                  VARCHAR2(25 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    sueldo                 int(11) NOT NULL,
    profesor_id_profesor   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    dir_esc_id_director    varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX contrato__idx ON
    contrato (
        profesor_id_profesor
    ASC );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX contrato__idxv1 ON
    contrato (
        dir_esc_id_director
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE contrato ADD CONSTRAINT contrato_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_contrato );

CREATE TABLE dir_esc (
    id_director            varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre                 varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    apellido               varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    telefono               int(11) NOT NULL,
    correo                 VARCHAR2(35),
    contrato_id_contrato   VARCHAR2(25 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    escuela_id_escuela     varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dir_esc__idx ON
    dir_esc (
        escuela_id_escuela
    ASC );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dir_esc__idxv1 ON
    dir_esc (
        contrato_id_contrato
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE dir_esc ADD CONSTRAINT dir_esc_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_director );

CREATE TABLE escuela (
    id_escuela            varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre                varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    dir_esc_id_director   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX escuela__idx ON
    escuela (
        dir_esc_id_director
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE escuela ADD CONSTRAINT escuela_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_escuela );

CREATE TABLE notas (
    id_nota                    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nota                       int(11),
    asignatura_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE notas ADD CONSTRAINT notas_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_nota );

CREATE TABLE profesor (
    id_profesor             varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre                  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    apellido                varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    correo                  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    contrato_id_contrato    VARCHAR2(25 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    escuela_id_escuela      varchar(25),
    seccion_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    seccion_id_seccion      varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX profesor__idx ON
    profesor (
        contrato_id_contrato
    ASC );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX profesor__idxv1 ON
    profesor (
        seccion_id_asignatura
    ASC,
        seccion_id_seccion
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE profesor ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_profesor );

CREATE TABLE relation_7 (
    alumno_id_alumno           varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    asignatura_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE relation_7 ADD CONSTRAINT relation_7_pk PRIMARY KEY ( alumno_id_alumno,
                                                                  asignatura_id_asignatura );

CREATE TABLE seccion (
    id_seccion                 varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    horario                    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    sala                       varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    asignatura_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    horario_2                  VARCHAR2(60 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    profesor_id_profesor       varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX seccion__idx ON
    seccion (
        profesor_id_profesor
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE seccion ADD CONSTRAINT seccion_pk PRIMARY KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura,
                                                            id_seccion );

ALTER TABLE alumno
    ADD CONSTRAINT alumno_carrera_fk FOREIGN KEY ( carrera_id_carrera )
        REFERENCES carrera ( id_carrera );

ALTER TABLE carrera
    ADD CONSTRAINT carrera_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY ( escuela_id_escuela )
        REFERENCES escuela ( id_escuela );

ALTER TABLE contrato
    ADD CONSTRAINT contrato_dir_esc_fk FOREIGN KEY ( dir_esc_id_director )
        REFERENCES dir_esc ( id_director );

ALTER TABLE contrato
    ADD CONSTRAINT contrato_profesor_fk FOREIGN KEY ( profesor_id_profesor )
        REFERENCES profesor ( id_profesor );

ALTER TABLE dir_esc
    ADD CONSTRAINT dir_esc_contrato_fk FOREIGN KEY ( contrato_id_contrato )
        REFERENCES contrato ( id_contrato );

ALTER TABLE dir_esc
    ADD CONSTRAINT dir_esc_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY ( escuela_id_escuela )
        REFERENCES escuela ( id_escuela );

ALTER TABLE escuela
    ADD CONSTRAINT escuela_dir_esc_fk FOREIGN KEY ( dir_esc_id_director )
        REFERENCES dir_esc ( id_director );

ALTER TABLE notas
    ADD CONSTRAINT notas_asignatura_fk FOREIGN KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura )
        REFERENCES asignatura ( id_asignatura );

ALTER TABLE profesor
    ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_contrato_fk FOREIGN KEY ( contrato_id_contrato )
        REFERENCES contrato ( id_contrato );

ALTER TABLE profesor
    ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY ( escuela_id_escuela )
        REFERENCES escuela ( id_escuela );

ALTER TABLE profesor
    ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_seccion_fk FOREIGN KEY ( seccion_id_asignatura,
                                                     seccion_id_seccion )
        REFERENCES seccion ( asignatura_id_asignatura,
                             id_seccion );

ALTER TABLE relation_7
    ADD CONSTRAINT relation_7_alumno_fk FOREIGN KEY ( alumno_id_alumno )
        REFERENCES alumno ( id_alumno );

ALTER TABLE relation_7
    ADD CONSTRAINT relation_7_asignatura_fk FOREIGN KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura )
        REFERENCES asignatura ( id_asignatura );

ALTER TABLE seccion
    ADD CONSTRAINT seccion_asignatura_fk FOREIGN KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura )
        REFERENCES asignatura ( id_asignatura );

ALTER TABLE seccion
    ADD CONSTRAINT seccion_profesor_fk FOREIGN KEY ( profesor_id_profesor )
        REFERENCES profesor ( id_profesor );
```

Comment: show you exact error message ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was

varchar2 to varchar
and numeric to int

Just was syntaxis

Here's the answer

```
-- Generado por Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 18.2.0.179.0756
--   en        2018-07-29 004217 CLT
--   sitio      Oracle Database 11g
--   tipo      Oracle Database 11g



CREATE TABLE alumno (
    id_alumno            varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre               varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    apellido             varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    ciudad               varchar(25),
    region               varchar(25),
    carrera_id_carrera   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE alumno ADD CONSTRAINT alumno_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_alumno );

CREATE TABLE asignatura (
    id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre          varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    horario         varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE asignatura ADD CONSTRAINT asignatura_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_asignatura );

CREATE TABLE carrera (
    id_carrera           varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre               varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    escuela_id_escuela   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE carrera ADD CONSTRAINT carrera_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_carrera );

CREATE TABLE contrato (
    id_contrato            VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    cargo                  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    sueldo                 int(11) NOT NULL,
    profesor_id_profesor   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    dir_esc_id_director    varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX contrato__idx ON
    contrato (
        profesor_id_profesor
    ASC );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX contrato__idxv1 ON
    contrato (
        dir_esc_id_director
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE contrato ADD CONSTRAINT contrato_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_contrato );

CREATE TABLE dir_esc (
    id_director            varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre                 varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    apellido               varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    telefono               int(11) NOT NULL,
    correo                 VARCHAR(35),
    contrato_id_contrato   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    escuela_id_escuela     varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dir_esc__idx ON
    dir_esc (
        escuela_id_escuela
    ASC );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dir_esc__idxv1 ON
    dir_esc (
        contrato_id_contrato
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE dir_esc ADD CONSTRAINT dir_esc_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_director );

CREATE TABLE escuela (
    id_escuela            varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre                varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    dir_esc_id_director   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX escuela__idx ON
    escuela (
        dir_esc_id_director
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE escuela ADD CONSTRAINT escuela_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_escuela );

CREATE TABLE notas (
    id_nota                    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nota                       int(11),
    asignatura_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE notas ADD CONSTRAINT notas_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_nota );

CREATE TABLE profesor (
    id_profesor             varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    nombre                  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    apellido                varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    correo                  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    contrato_id_contrato    VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    escuela_id_escuela      varchar(25),
    seccion_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    seccion_id_seccion      varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX profesor__idx ON
    profesor (
        contrato_id_contrato
    ASC );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX profesor__idxv1 ON
    profesor (
        seccion_id_asignatura
    ASC,
        seccion_id_seccion
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE profesor ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_profesor );

CREATE TABLE relation_7 (
    alumno_id_alumno           varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    asignatura_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE relation_7 ADD CONSTRAINT relation_7_pk PRIMARY KEY ( alumno_id_alumno,
                                                                  asignatura_id_asignatura );

CREATE TABLE seccion (
    id_seccion                 varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    horario                    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    sala                       varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    asignatura_id_asignatura   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    horario_2                  VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    profesor_id_profesor       varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX seccion__idx ON
    seccion (
        profesor_id_profesor
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE seccion ADD CONSTRAINT seccion_pk PRIMARY KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura,
                                                            id_seccion );

ALTER TABLE alumno
    ADD CONSTRAINT alumno_carrera_fk FOREIGN KEY ( carrera_id_carrera )
        REFERENCES carrera ( id_carrera );

ALTER TABLE carrera
    ADD CONSTRAINT carrera_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY ( escuela_id_escuela )
        REFERENCES escuela ( id_escuela );

ALTER TABLE contrato
    ADD CONSTRAINT contrato_dir_esc_fk FOREIGN KEY ( dir_esc_id_director )
        REFERENCES dir_esc ( id_director );

ALTER TABLE contrato
    ADD CONSTRAINT contrato_profesor_fk FOREIGN KEY ( profesor_id_profesor )
        REFERENCES profesor ( id_profesor );

ALTER TABLE dir_esc
    ADD CONSTRAINT dir_esc_contrato_fk FOREIGN KEY ( contrato_id_contrato )
        REFERENCES contrato ( id_contrato );

ALTER TABLE dir_esc
    ADD CONSTRAINT dir_esc_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY ( escuela_id_escuela )
        REFERENCES escuela ( id_escuela );

ALTER TABLE escuela
    ADD CONSTRAINT escuela_dir_esc_fk FOREIGN KEY ( dir_esc_id_director )
        REFERENCES dir_esc ( id_director );

ALTER TABLE notas
    ADD CONSTRAINT notas_asignatura_fk FOREIGN KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura )
        REFERENCES asignatura ( id_asignatura );

ALTER TABLE profesor
    ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_contrato_fk FOREIGN KEY ( contrato_id_contrato )
        REFERENCES contrato ( id_contrato );

ALTER TABLE profesor
    ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY ( escuela_id_escuela )
        REFERENCES escuela ( id_escuela );

ALTER TABLE profesor
    ADD CONSTRAINT profesor_seccion_fk FOREIGN KEY ( seccion_id_asignatura,
                                                     seccion_id_seccion )
        REFERENCES seccion ( asignatura_id_asignatura,
                             id_seccion );

ALTER TABLE relation_7
    ADD CONSTRAINT relation_7_alumno_fk FOREIGN KEY ( alumno_id_alumno )
        REFERENCES alumno ( id_alumno );

ALTER TABLE relation_7
    ADD CONSTRAINT relation_7_asignatura_fk FOREIGN KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura )
        REFERENCES asignatura ( id_asignatura );

ALTER TABLE seccion
    ADD CONSTRAINT seccion_asignatura_fk FOREIGN KEY ( asignatura_id_asignatura )
        REFERENCES asignatura ( id_asignatura );

ALTER TABLE seccion
    ADD CONSTRAINT seccion_profesor_fk FOREIGN KEY ( profesor_id_profesor )
        REFERENCES profesor ( id_profesor );



-- Informe de Resumen de Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 
-- 
-- CREATE TABLE                            10
-- CREATE INDEX                             8
-- ALTER TABLE                             25
-- CREATE VIEW                              0
-- ALTER VIEW                               0
-- CREATE PACKAGE                           0
-- CREATE PACKAGE BODY                      0
-- CREATE PROCEDURE                         0
-- CREATE FUNCTION                          0
-- CREATE TRIGGER                           0
-- ALTER TRIGGER                            0
-- CREATE COLLECTION TYPE                   0
-- CREATE STRUCTURED TYPE                   0
-- CREATE STRUCTURED TYPE BODY              0
-- CREATE CLUSTER                           0
-- CREATE CONTEXT                           0
-- CREATE DATABASE                          0
-- CREATE DIMENSION                         0
-- CREATE DIRECTORY                         0
-- CREATE DISK GROUP                        0
-- CREATE ROLE                              0
-- CREATE ROLLBACK SEGMENT                  0
-- CREATE SEQUENCE                          0
-- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW                 0
-- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG             0
-- CREATE SYNONYM                           0
-- CREATE TABLESPACE                        0
-- CREATE USER                              0
-- 
-- DROP TABLESPACE                          0
-- DROP DATABASE                            0
-- 
-- REDACTION POLICY                         0
-- 
-- ORDS DROP SCHEMA                         0
-- ORDS ENABLE SCHEMA                       0
-- ORDS ENABLE OBJECT                       0
-- 
-- ERRORS                                   0
-- WARNINGS                                 0
```